# Issue with parsing LocalDate to Date in Java

Tags: java, date, parsing, localdate

I am trying to parse LocalDate to date in my Java code but I keep getting the following error:

> {code: "unknown.unexpected", detail: "Text '02/28/1936' could not be parsed at index 0", meta: null}

My code is as follows:

```
private Date dateOfBirth;
public SearchByDateCommand(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth != null ? Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth) : null;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Which `Date` type is this? I can't see a `Date.valueOf` method in `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @JonSkeet using java.sql.date

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify that then, given that `java.util.Date` is far more commonly used than `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: I'm surprised that the code you've shown throws the exception you've described though. Could you please include the stack trace? Are you certain that it's getting as far as the body of that method at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
private Date dateOfBirth;
public SearchByDateCommand(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth != null ? Date.from(dateOfBirth.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()) : null;
}
```

You will have to add a time to the LocalDate, interpret the date and time within a time zone, get the number of seconds / milliseconds since epoch, and lastly, create a java.util.Date.